# UITableView contentOffset issue in iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, contentoffset

I am using [RATreeView](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView) in one of my app, but facing some weird issue with content Offset (pls correct me if I am wrong). Visited many threads over "SO" about the same but no luck.

I m having some checkbox in each cell of table view, there are n number of cells, lets say on first launch I have 20 cells visible, now I want to click other checkbox so I scrolled down and now if I clicked on last checkbox of TableView the contentOffset (y offset) gets changed and table scrolled to down. **THIS ISSUE is only with iso 7 not with ios 6.**

In viewDidLoad -

```
if([[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][0] intValue] >= 7) 
{
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

Inside chekboxClickAction - To reload the table
This is what I tried -

//------Approach 1----->>

```
CGPoint offset = [[self treeView] contentOffset];
[self.treeView reloadData];
self.treeView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(offset.x, offset.y);
```

//------Approach 2----->>

```
CGPoint offset = [[self treeView] contentOffset];
[self.treeView reloadData];
[self.treeView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, offset.y)];
[self.treeView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)];
```

But no luck.

Below are the scenarios mentioned in the image1 and Image2.

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you should ask the `RATreeView`'s developer about it, if you have not figured out how his component works – or you can implement an own tree-view which you can control entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue and found this question.

It seems if I restore the contentSize too it scrolls back where it was before ( my items are constant however, the code needs some adjustments for dynamic stuff ).

```
CGPoint crtOffset = self.treeView.contentOffset;
CGSize beforeContentSize = self.treeView.contentSize;
[self.treeView reloadData];
for (RADataObject * item in self.items)
{
    [self.treeView expandRowForItem:item withRowAnimation:RATreeViewRowAnimationNone];
}

self.treeView.contentSize = beforeContentSize;
self.treeView.contentOffset = crtOffset;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this work around to fix contentOffset reset on iOS7

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setContentOffset) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```